# Click event on GMappanel return undefined extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am tryin addListener(map, 'click', function(e) for my gmappanel but it doesnt work return undef how to make that addListener(map, 'click', function(e) work
Can someone tell how to make that because Ive search all internet and find only for javascript not for extjs how to hung that function on click ?onrender?Help
My view:

```
Ext.define('Pandora.view.Group.GroupForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.GroupForm',

    title: '',
    operation: '',
    //width   : 350,
    //layout  : 'fit',


    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    initComponent: function () {
        me = this;
        console.log(me.operation);

        //  console.log(me);
        this.autoShow = true;
        this.width = 550;
        this.height = 650;


        this.items = [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'title',
                value: me.login,
                fieldLabel: 'Title',
                allowBlank: false,
                width: 330,
                style: {
                    marginTop: '10px',
                    marginLeft: '20px',
                    marginRight: '20px'
                }
            },



            {
                title: 'Google Map',
                width: 535,
                height: 800,
                //   frame:true,
                id: 'gmapForm',
                //  height: '100%',
                xtype: 'gmappanel',
                /*  listeners: {
                 click: function(e){
                 Ext.Msg.alert('It\'s fine', 'and it\'s art.');
                 }
                 }*/
                               /*afterrender: {
                 click: function (e) {
                 console.log("a++");
                 Ext.Msg.alert('point_lat',
                 'and its art.');
                 GEvent.addListener(this.map, "click",
                 function () {
                 alert("You clicked the map.");
                 });

                 }

                 //   Ext.Msg.alert('It\'s fine', 'and it\'s art.');

                 //fn: setupWindow,
                 //scope: this
                 }*/

            gmapType    :        'map',
            center
                :        {
            geoCodeAddr: "221B Baker Street",
                marker      :
            {
                title: 'Holmes Home'
            }
        }
        ,
                listeners:{

                    afterrender: {

                        fn: this.addMapListener,
                        scope: this
                    },
                    el: {
                        click: function (e) {
                            alert('click');
                            console.log(e.latLng);
                        }
                      /*  google.maps.event.addListener(trafficMap, 'click', function(e) {
                            // infowindow.open(googleMapComp, marker);
                            console.log('sssssssssss');
                        })*/
                    }
                },

        /* listeners: {

         click: function (e) {
         console.log("a");
         Ext.Msg.alert('point_lat',
         'and its art.');
         GEvent.addListener(this.map, "click",
         function () {
         alert("You clicked the map.");
         });

         }
         },*/

        mapConfOpts: ['enableScrollWheelZoom', 'enableDoubleClickZoom', 'enableDragging'],
            mapControls
        :
        ['GSmallMapControl', 'GMapTypeControl', 'NonExistantControl'],
            mapOptions
        :
        {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }}

        /*listeners: {

         maprender: function(extMapComponent, googleMapComp){

         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: position = new google.maps.LatLng (42.16726190,-87.83146810),
         // position: patientPosition,   //patientPosition initialized in geocodePatientAddress() function in Home.js
         map: googleMapComp,
         animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
         draggable: false,
         title: 'Patient Location'

         });

         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
         // infowindow.open(googleMapComp, marker);
         console.log('sssssssssss');
         });

         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
         infowindow.close(googleMapComp, marker);
         });
         }

         },*/
        /*   handler : function () {
         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
         // infowindow.open(googleMapComp, marker);
         console.log('sssssssssss');
         });
         // this.up('window').down('form').getForm().reset();
         }*/


        /* google.maps.event.addListener(gObject, "click", function(e){
         alert('test');
         })*/


        ]
        ;
        this.buttons = [
            {
                text: me.operation,
                name: me.operation,
                scope: this
            },
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                scope: this,
                handler: this.close
            }
        ];
        console.log(arguments);
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    addMapListener:function(){
        console.log("addMapListenervieew");
        var trafficMap = Ext.getCmp('gmapForm');
        google.maps.event.addListener(trafficMap, 'click', function(e) {
            // infowindow.open(googleMapComp, marker);
            console.log('sssssssssss');
        });
        /*GEvent.bind(this.gmap, 'click', this, function(){
           // this.onMapReady();
        });*/
       // var me = this;
        //Ext.widget('EventForm',{title:me.selectedRow.name+"'s Event",id:me.selectedRow.id});
    }
   /*GEvent.bind(this.gmap, 'click', this, function(){
        this.onMapReady();
    });*/
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure you declared your click event the right way. Try this way :  listeners: {
       afterrender: function(gmppanel) {
           gmppanel.el.on('click', function() {
               alert('clicked');
           });
        }
    }

Comment: Yes maybe its not in the right way,because I dont know how to implement google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {} where I should make that because I need e object

Comment: I am using extJs and this is for Js google map

Comment: @Benoit Cuvelier can you help